# Does HBase support nested transactions (or something equivalent)?

Tags: hbase

I want to run tests that modify data, assert that the changes were made correctly, and then roll back the changes.  In typical database parlance, this would be called starting a transaction and later rolling it back.

I am limited by MySql because the application code uses transactions, so the tests can't further encapsulate the application's changes in transactions.

If I switch to HBase (which I have other reasons for considering, e.g. scale), could I do something like this?  This is a case of not-sure-what-to-google-for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, there are very few databases out there that support truly nested transactions. However, both MySQL and Postgres support `SAVEPOINT`  which can be used to accomplish what you are trying to do. If you are using an ORM like rails; it should already be able to handle such a use case.

**Transactions in HBase**

Apache HBase does not support transactions in the conventional sense i.e. it does not provide you capability to start and then rollback an operation.The only transactional guarantees that HBase provides are:

1. Atomicity of operations at a row-level.
2. Any scan operation running on a HBase region will see the state of data as it was at the start of the scan. It won't see new data that was written to the region while the scan was running.

My advice is not to have similar expectations from a NoSQL database as you would have from a relational database. HBase is good at handling tens of petabytes of data for doing high volume point updates, point reads and range scans. However, managing an HBase cluster is a lot more involved task than managing a MySQL instance. You'll need to drop many of the requirements that you would place on a relational database while moving to HBase.

That said, there are workarounds to what you are trying to do, which may or may not work based on your exact setup. You could just cleanup the whole DB/table before the start of each test.

Another approach to deal with this is to use another engine on top of HBase that provides SQL like semantics. [Apache Phoenix](https://phoenix.apache.org/index.html) is one such project that has a very active developer community. They have rolled out cross-row transaction support in the latest release (the support is still in beta, and of course, no nested transactions here either).

Comment: Regarding point 2 where `any scan operation running on a HBase region will see the state of data as it was at the start of the scan`, if this is the case then can we say that HBase follows CP of CAP theorem when it doesn't truly provide consistency?

Comment: @pacman That's incorrect. Consistency means that every read will receive the most recent write. However, the frame of reference for the most recent write changes in different systems. For the purpose of the scan operation, "most recent write" means the one that finished just before the scan operation started, and no writes after that are seen. This is usually called snapshot isolation (or repeatable read) in databases and most SQL databases would default to this behaviour HBases exhibits.

Comment: >  most SQL databases would default to this behaviour HBases exhibits

I meant most SQL databases would also support this behaviour that HBase also exhibits.